# Disable routing cache in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to get started with symfony3 and while playing around with some controllers and routes I face the problem that every time I load a specific route any further changes on a controller class are not recognized by symfony until I clear the routing cache.

For example:

creating a LuckyController

creating a numberAction

Test it.

After that creating a numbers2Action

Now the route for numbers2Action isnt found until I do a console cache:clear

This seems very annoying for testing/developing. I searched for possibilities to disable the cache for dev environment but didnt found a solution yet.
(e.g. tried to // $kernel->loadClassCache(); in app_dev.php but this didnt work for me)

Is there a way to disable the routing cache (or another way to workarround this problem) for developing?

Thanks

Edit: I'm using app_dev.php

Answer (score 2):

There's a specific developement environment that comes with symfony-standard that you can use when you're developing or debugging your application: [`app_dev.php`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/app_dev.php). You can use `app.php` for production.

Comment: I use app_dev.php but symfony nevertheless uses the routing cache.

Comment: I'm sure that it does, but in `debug` mode a metadata is generated with all the path of configuration file and controller that use annotation involved in a creation of a route. If you modify one of those file, the router is regenerated. Have you disabled this behaviour  with `$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', false);`?

Comment: No, it's still $kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);